# How to compile bouncycastle leightweight API for J2ME

Tags: api, compilation, java-me, bouncycastle

I haven't been able to compile the bouncycastle leightweight API with the ant build script file included in the package. I have set the path to WTK in "crypto_env.properties" but without success. Have anybody else been able to compile it and if so, how?

EDIT:

I have peeked at the ant build script shipped with the bouncycastle package and tried to make my own build script. My build script (which follows) results in build error, though.

```
<project name="midp" default="compile" basedir=".">
  <property name="wtk" location="/WTK2.5.2_01"/>
  <property name="src" location="src"/>
  <property name="build" location="build"/>

  <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
  </target>

  <property name="midp-api-jar" value="/${wtk}/lib/midpapi20.jar"/>

  <path id="classpath">
    <pathelement location="${midp-api-jar}"/>
    <pathelement location="/${wtk}/lib/cldcapi10.jar"/>
  </path>

  <patternset id="java-namespace-set">
    <include name="java/**/*.java"/>
  </patternset>

  <target name="compile" depends="init">
    <javac srcdir="${src}"
           destdir="${build}"
           bootclasspath="${midp-api-jar}"
           includeAntRuntime="no"
           includeJavaRuntime="no"
           debug="off"
           optimize="off">
      <patternset refid="java-namespace-set"/>
      <classpath refid = "classpath"/>
    </javac>
  </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you read item number 3 in the [FAQ](http://bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Frequently+Asked+Questions)?